# Validate a subgroup of ISO 8859

Tags: javascript, regex

Is possible with regular expressions validate if a text have alphanumeric characters (a-z,A-Z,0-9) and some characters of ISO 8859? for example characters in the group in Dec code 192 (À) to  character in dec  code 214 (Ö)
http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-1

Comment: Do want to have at least one of those characters, or only those characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\xc0-\xd6]
```

...or something along those lines. In `\xXX` the X'es are hexadecimal character codes from `\x00` to `\xFF`. Use [your own reference link](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-1) for the correct codes.

You can also specify unicode characters using `\uXXXXX` where the X'es are the unicode codepoints.

Comment: In case someone wants something more accurate, the complete set for ISO-8859-1 is [\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\x7E\xA0-\xFF], and as a regular expression it could be /^[\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\x7E\xA0-\xFF]*$/. Reference: http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~stolfi/EXPORT/www/ISO-8859-1-Encoding.html

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can. Use this page to test your characters: http://xregexp.com/tests/unicode.html

Comment: Apart from the question being "Is it possible?", its obvious point was to provide a feasible solution to check for ISO 8859 characters, not to know that "Yes you can".